# Why derived class failed to visit protected member of base class？

Tags: c++, oop

Talk is cheap, show you the code：

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Message {
protected:
    virtual string json() const = 0;
};

class _messageChain_ final: public Message {
public:
    string json() const override;
private:
    vector<Message *>messages;
};

string _messageChain_::json() const
{
    string json;
    for ( Message *msg : messages )
        json += msg->json();
    return json;
}

int main ( void )
{

}
```

When I tried to compiling it:

```bash
main.cpp: In member function ‘virtual std::string _messageChain_::json() const’:
main.cpp:21:21: error: ‘virtual std::string Message::json() const’ is protected within this context
   21 |   json += msg->json();
      |                     ^
main.cpp:7:17: note: declared protected here
    7 |  virtual string json() const = 0;
```

I think the `protected` will makes `_messageChain_` be able to access the member (`virtual string json();`) of Message, in the function `string _messageChain_::json()const;`.

But it didn't.

If I add `_messageChain_` as a friend to `Message` or replace `protected` with `public`，it will work. If I add `string _messageChain_::json()const;` as a friend, it won't work.

I'm confused why `protected` and `friend <function>`doesn't work but `friend class _messageChain` does.

Comment: Unrelated - having a variable in the function that has the same name as the function does not help clarity (or maintainability).

Answer (score 2):

From [Protected_member_access](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access#Protected_member_access) (emphasis mine):

> A protected member of a class is only accessible
>
> 1. to the members and friends of that class;
> 2. to the members of any derived class of that class, **but only** when the class of the object through which the protected member is accessed is that **derived class** or a derived class of that derived class:

So you can access `Message::json` only from a `_messageChain_` object.